# Online c# application

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to develop a payroll application with a C# front end and Oracle XE database backup.

My application works fine in a local system.

I want to deploy it online. Simply run a setup file on client system, or type an IP address in browser and my application will open.

How can I do this?

Comment: Your question is quite vague, the only reason I'm leaving it open is because I think @Andy figured out what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but here is a possible option:

[ClickOnce Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28VS.80%29.aspx)

ClickOnce allows you to deploy Windows apps in a consistent, controlled manner.  You can host the deployment on a web site, a network file share, or in a couple other configurations.